# Gatling error during compilation for assertion

Tags: scala, gatling

I was previously using gatling mvn plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
            </plugin>
```

Now I have added the below dependency because I wanted to use a feature added in that version

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

And it gives compilation error

```
Symbol 'type io.gatling.commons.shared.unstable.model.stats.assertion.AssertionPathParts' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'method io.gatling.core.assertion.AssertionSupport.string2PathParts'.
Make sure that type AssertionPathParts is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'AssertionSupport.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of io.gatling.commons.shared.unstable.model.stats.assertion.
    val feeder: BatchableFeederBuilder[String]#F = csv(usersFile).circular
                                                   ^
```

The code sample is

```
object UserFeeder {
    val feeder: BatchableFeederBuilder[String]#F = csv(usersFile).circular
  }
```